# Валидация на уровне модели CodeIgniter

Tags: mvc, codeigniter, валидация

Добрый день, возник вопрос как использовать хелпер [form_validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) фреймворка CodeIgniter для переменных?
Ситуация такая, сейчас структура сайта имеет следующий вид:

Клинет отправляет ajax запрос, запрос приходит в $this->input->post() в контроллер. Контроллер выбирвает нужный метод модели и подставляет в него POST данные.

```
public function ajax() {

    if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() )
        show_404();

    $action = $this->input->post("action");

    switch ($action) {

        case 'published':
            $p = $this->input->post('published');
            echo json_encode($this->page->published($p));
            break;

        ...
```

Теперь когда модель получила данные, она должна их валидировать.

```
public function published($published) {
    // тут должна быть валидация. Как валидировать переменную $published методами CI?
}
```

Способ валидации форм показанный в [документации](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) не устраивает, так как в невозможно явно указать какую переменую проверять (проверять можно только данные которые находятся в $this->input->post() ).

Вопрос, можно ли как-то использовать валидатор CI для произвольных переменных вне $this->input->post() ?
Не хотелось бы подключать что-то стороннее или писать регулярки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ваши данные и находятся в `$this->input->post()`. Сначала выполните валидацию, потом уже передавайте в модель.

Comment: Наверное я плохо изложил суть вопроса, возможно ли просто любую переменную проверить средствами CI?
Понятно что и внутри модели можно, задав правила валидации, вызывать $this->form_validation->run() и все отработает.
Понимаете, как-бы если мне нужно валидировать данные пришедшие по POST проблем не возникает.

Comment: Но давайте представим ситуацию когда у нас есть метод модели или контроллера (не суть):
public function foo($a) {}
Данные в метод foo() приходят не по POST, а скажем вызовом этого метода из другого места скрипта.
Вопрос: Могу ли я как-то проверить $a внутри метода используя функционал заложенный в form_validation?

Comment: Можете. Например, $this->form_validation->valid_email($p), где $p - ваша переменная. Также можно использовать все другие проверки.